# Spring JPA - Why is my findAll returning null when there is data in my database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a crudrepository for an entity that I am attempting to query. The entity in question is a mapping of two other entities (two foreign keys) to another column of values. The "middle table" is RoleMapSkill and uses the id of tables role and skill as foreign keys. When I call the findAll method in the crud repository I receive a null pointer (see below).

I know there is data in the database, but for some reason it is not being returned.

Please see below my entity class, repository and controller;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at main.SearchController.getRoleSkills(SearchController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

Entity;

```
package main;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class RoleMapSkill {
    @Id
    private String mapId;
    @OneToOne
    Role role;
    @OneToOne
    Skill skill;

    private String rating;
//  
//  public RoleMapSkill(){
//      
//    }
    public RoleMapSkill(String Id, Role idRole, Skill idSkill, String rating){
        this.mapId=Id;
        this.role=idRole;
        this.skill=idSkill;
        this.rating=rating;
    }
    public String getIdRoleSkillRatings() {
        return mapId;
    }
    public void setIdRoleSkillRatings(String idRoleSkillRatings) {
        this.mapId = idRoleSkillRatings;
    }
    public Role getIdRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setIdRole(Role idRole) {
        this.role = idRole;
    }
    public Skill getIdSkill() {
        return skill;
    }
    public void setIdSkill(Skill idSkill) {
        this.skill = idSkill;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

Repo;

```
package main;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoleMapSkillRepository extends CrudRepository<RoleMapSkill, Integer> {

    List<RoleMapSkill> findAll();
    @Query(value = "SELECT t FROM RoleMapSkill t RIGHT JOIN FETCH t.role where t.role = tester")            
    Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> test(String tester);
//     Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> findAllByroleIs(String roleId);


    }
```

Controller

```
package main;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SearchController {
      public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
      public RoleRepository roleRepository; 
      public SkillRepository skillRepository;   
      public RoleMapSkillRepository roleMapSkillRepository;

      @Autowired
        public void  employeeRepository(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository){
            this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }
      @Autowired
        public void  roleRepository(RoleRepository roleRepository){
            this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }
      @Autowired
        public void  skillRepository(SkillRepository skillRepository){
            this.skillRepository = skillRepository;
        }
//    @Autowired
//      public void  roleSkillRatingsRepository(roleSkillRatingsRepository roleSkillRatingsRepository){
//          this.roleSkillRatingsRepository = roleSkillRatingsRepository;
//      }


      @ResponseBody
        public List<Employee> getAllemployees() {
            System.out.println(employeeRepository.findAll());
            return employeeRepository.findAll();
        }

      @GetMapping("/test") 
      @ResponseBody
        public Map<String,Integer> getRoleSkills(String roleName) {
          //    List<Role> currentRole=roleRepository.findAll();
            Optional<Role> currentRole=roleRepository.findByroleNameIs("SWEM");
            String roleId=currentRole.get().getRoleId();
        //  Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> skills = roleMapSkillRepository.test(roleId);
        //  List<RoleMapSkill> test=roleMapSkillRepository.findAll();
       //   System.out.print(test.get(0).getRating());
            List<RoleMapSkill> test=roleMapSkillRepository.findAll();
            System.out.print(test.get(0).getIdRoleSkillRatings());
            Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> skills = roleMapSkillRepository.test(roleId);
            System.out.println(skills.get().get(0).getIdSkill());
//          System.out.print(currentRole.get(0).getRoleId());
//          System.out.print(currentRole.get(0).getRoleName());
//          System.out.print(currentRole.get(1).getRoleId());
//          System.out.print(currentRole.get(1).getRoleName());
        //  roleSkillRatingsRepository.findAllById(Integer.valueOf(currentRole.getIdRole()));
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you re-activate the default constructor for your `@Entity`-class? Which line is line 52 in the controller?

Comment: What do you mean by re-activate sorry? Line 52 is this List<RoleMapSkill> test=roleMapSkillRepository.findAll();

Comment: Please remove the findAll method from your repository and use the default one

Comment: @nu7m3g I meant un-commenting the default-constructor.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, the default constructor being reactivated doesn't seem to help. I will edit the post to include all of the controller code

Comment: @HediAyed is that not the default?

Comment: I've just re read this and realised I didn't add an @AutoWired for the repo

Comment: Seems like you are missing an injection-point (setter) for `RoleMapSkillRepository`. I would suggest to switch to constructor-based injection and set all injected repositories `final`. This reduces the risk of such an error to occurr. A comment on your code: I would suggest using JEE's `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `findAll()` method from `RoleMapSkillRepository`. Because it deactivates the default one. When you extends the `CrudRepository` you have to add Entity object and Entity object's Id data type. Your `RoleMapSkill` entity Id data type is `String`. So you have to change `RoleMapSkillRepository` as below:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleMapSkillRepository extends CrudRepository<RoleMapSkill, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM RoleMapSkill t RIGHT JOIN FETCH t.role where t.role = tester")            
Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> test(String tester);
//     Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> findAllByroleIs(String roleId);
}
```

Use `@Autowired` annotations inside controller as below:

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Autowired
    public RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    public SkillRepository skillRepository;
    @Autowired
    public RoleMapSkillRepository roleMapSkillRepository;

    //Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When one inspects the code presented closely, one will find that there is no injection point (setter) for `RoleMapSkillRepository`. Thus, the `NullPointerException` arises when `findAll()` is called on `roleMapSkillRepository` since the reference is `null`.

To prevent this from happening again, I would suggest switching to constructor-based injection and set all injected fields to `final`:

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {
     private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
     private final RoleRepository roleRepository; 
     private final SkillRepository skillRepository;   
     private final RoleMapSkillRepository roleMapSkillRepository;

    @Inject
    public SearchController(
            final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository,
            final RoleRepository roleRepository,
            final SkillRepository skillRepository,
            RoleMapSkillRepository roleMapSkillRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.skillRepository = skillRepository;
        this.roleMapSkillRepository = roleMapSkillRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

This way, if a field is not injected, the program will not compile.

---

A comment on your code: I would suggest using [JSR-330's `@Inject`-annotation](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330).

Answer (score 0):

please check if data is available or not before getting from Optional

**Optional<>** class **isPresent()** method

```
if(currentRole.isPresent()){
   String roleId=currentRole.get().getRoleId();
}

List<RoleMapSkill> test=roleMapSkillRepository.findAll();
   if(test != null && !test.isEmpty()){
     System.out.print(test.get(0).getIdRoleSkillRatings());
   }


Optional<List<RoleMapSkill>> skills = roleMapSkillRepository.test(roleId);
   if(skills.isPresent() && !skills.get().isEmpty()){
     System.out.println(skills.get().get(0).getIdSkill());
   }
```